# Can't get valid values from text fields using jQuery selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to grab some values from text fields, these values represent dates, and are made up of three parts the year, month and day. There are two such dates, the `first` and `last` date, together they form 'bounds' to restrict a search.

When I use the following js/jquery on the HTML below I get nonsense results.

I've put the HTML and JS into Jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/grHEY/

And copied the code below as well.

```
$(".date").click
        (
            function ()
            {
                var dateValueElement = this;
                var propertyId = dateValueElement.id;
                $(".numberBounds").filter("#"+propertyId).toggle();
                handle_date_change(dateValueElement);
            }
        );


function handle_date_change(dateValueElement){

var first_year = $(".firstYear").filter("#"+dateValueElement.id).val();
var first_month = $(".firstMonth").filter("#"+dateValueElement.id).val();
var first_day = $(".firstDay").filter("#"+dateValueElement.id).val();
var last_year = $(".lastYear").filter("#"+dateValueElement.id).val();
var last_month = $(".lastMonth").filter("#"+dateValueElement.id).val();
var last_day = $(".lastDay").filter("#"+dateValueElement.id).val();

}
```

---

```
<span style="display: inline;" class="numberBounds" id="74652">
    <input onkeyup="javascript:handle_date_change(this)" valuetype="date" id="74652" class="firstYear" value="1905" size="4" type="text">
    -<input onkeyup="javascript:handle_date_change(this)" valuetype="date" id="74652" class="firstMonth" value="08" size="2" type="text">
    -<input onkeyup="javascript:handle_date_change(this)" valuetype="date" id="74652" class="firstDay" value="07" size="2" type="text"> &lt; 
</span>
<span class="date tag half-padding margin" value="1905-08-07" id="74652">1905-08-07</span>
<span style="display: inline;" class="numberBounds" id="74652"> &lt; 
    <input onkeyup="javascript:handle_date_change(this)" valuetype="date" id="74652" class="lastYear" value="1905" size="4" type="text">
    -<input onkeyup="javascript:handle_date_change(this)" valuetype="date" id="74652" class="lastMonth" value="08" size="2" type="text">
    -<input onkeyup="javascript:handle_date_change(this)" valuetype="date" id="74652" class="lastDay" value="07" size="2" type="text">
</span>
```

Comment: Firebug console says "propertyId is not defined".

Comment: Sorry I didn't paste my code too well.

Comment: Using the same ID more than once is invalid in HTML, and will only give incorrect results (`getElementById()` will only return one element). Use classes instead.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, only at most 1 element may have a particular id. If two or more elements share the same id, then it is a violation of the DTD specification for the id attribute (IDREF).

A better way to group items is either by the class attribute or by the name attribute. If you use the name attribute, then document.getElementsByTagName("thename").length returns the number of elements with that name.

Comment: Thanks, that's useful to know. I'll change it over

Comment: Isn't `getElementsByName` HTML5 only? As long as the ID's are made unique, they can be used. A class for each type selected would work too.

Answer (score 0):

Your `propertyId` is not in a global scope. However, I don't think you need to use it in the global scope. Why don't you do this?

```
$(".date").click
        (
            function ()
            {
                var dateValueElement = this;
                var propertyId = dateValueElement.id;
                $(".numberBounds").filter("#"+propertyId).toggle();
                handle_date_change(dateValueElement, propertyId);
            }
        );


function handle_date_change(dateValueElement, propertyId){

    var first_year = $(".firstYear").filter("#"+dateValueElement.id).val();
    var first_month = $(".firstMonth").filter("#"+propertyId).val();
    var first_day = $(".firstDay").filter("#"+propertyId).val();
    var last_year = $(".lastYear").filter("#"+propertyId).val();
    var last_month = $(".lastMonth").filter("#"+propertyId).val();
    var last_day = $(".lastDay").filter("#"+propertyId).val();

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/grHEY/1/

Comment: Actually I might be able to eleminate the need to pass in dateValueElement altogether and just pass in the propertyId, will try now.

Comment: Just a thought (I've never used filter before), but doesn't it seem like a better fit to use find instead, filter seems to allow multiple selections (so maybe filter is outputting an array of one?), whereas find would only allow one.

Comment: @mazzzzz - Well, hopefully there is only one ID selected with the `#`.

Comment: haha, yeah, but I doubt jquery knows that.  It could be passing that out wrapped in an array, and you can't access .val() of an array.  It might not be (I couldn't get your code to work, much less throw an error :/)

Comment: The difference between `filter` and `find` is that `filter` reduces the set while `find` searches in the children of the elements in the set.

Comment: The jQuery object always has an array of elements even if there is only one element in the array. Functions like `val` will just use the first element in the array.

Comment: @mazzzzz - I don't think `find()` is doing what you think, either. :) http://jsfiddle.net/U7Bdf/

Comment: @Guffa Good to know, like I said, just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the difference is, but this worked:

```
        $(".date").click
        (
            function ()
            {
                var dateElement = this;
                var propertyId = dateElement.id;
console.info(propertyId);           
                $(".numberBounds").filter("#"+propertyId).toggle();
                handle_date_change(dateElement);
            }
        );
    }
);

// ------ START: handle tag clicks -------

function handle_date_change(dateElement){
// grab the component parts of the date and turn them into a String that MySQL can use as query parameter

var propertyId = dateElement.id;

// now we use normal filtering to get the appropriate values
var first_year = $(".firstYear").filter("#"+propertyId).val();
var first_month = $(".firstMonth").filter("#"+propertyId).val();
var first_day = $(".firstDay").filter("#"+propertyId).val();
var last_year = $(".lastYear").filter("#"+propertyId).val();
var last_month = $(".lastMonth").filter("#"+propertyId).val();
var last_day = $(".lastDay").filter("#"+propertyId).val();
console.info(first_year+" | "+first_month+" | "+first_day+" | "+last_year+" | "+last_month+" | "+last_day); 
}
```

Comment: You're just getting the id from the dateElement, which you pass in. It's the same as passing in the id after getting it from the dateElement in the click handler.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, think I figured it out, the problem is that you can't have multiple items with the same IDs (even if they are in different sections of the code). Try something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/grHEY/5/

Though, there are better ways of doing it.
Say http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/ (.data)
Or instead of storing that in the class, use php to set that to a variable in js (in the header).

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that you are using the same `id` for a lot of element. The `id` should be unique for an element. Also, an `id` should not start with a digit.

I removed the `id` from all the elements, and use the containing elements as scope to isolate the textboxes:

http://jsfiddle.net/grHEY/7/

HTML:

```
<span style="display: inline;" class="numberBounds">
    <input onkeyup="javascript:handle_date_change(this)" valuetype="date" class="firstYear" value="1905" size="4" type="text">
    -<input onkeyup="javascript:handle_date_change(this)" valuetype="date" class="firstMonth" value="08" size="2" type="text">
    -<input onkeyup="javascript:handle_date_change(this)" valuetype="date" class="firstDay" value="07" size="2" type="text"> &lt;
</span>
<span class="date tag half-padding margin" value="1905-08-07">1905-08-07</span>
<span style="display: inline;" class="numberBounds"> &lt;
    <input onkeyup="javascript:handle_date_change(this)" valuetype="date" class="lastYear" value="1905" size="4" type="text">
    -<input onkeyup="javascript:handle_date_change(this)" valuetype="date" class="lastMonth" value="08" size="2" type="text">
    -<input onkeyup="javascript:handle_date_change(this)" valuetype="date" class="lastDay" value="07" size="2" type="text">
</span>
```

Javascript:

```
$(".date").click(

function() {
    var first = $(this).prev();
    var last = $(this).next();
    first.toggle();
    last.toggle();
    handle_date_change(first, last);
});


function handle_date_change(first, last) {

    // now we use normal filtering to get the appropriate values
    var first_year = $(".firstYear", first).val();
    var first_month = $(".firstMonth", first).val();
    var first_day = $(".firstDay", first).val();
    var last_year = $(".lastYear", last).val();
    var last_month = $(".lastMonth", last).val();
    var last_day = $(".lastDay", last).val();

    alert(first_year);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where are you adding the class 'date' in the HTML? The click is binded to the span element, is that you want?